# View change from api19 to api23

Tags: android

[API 19 screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFXRV.png)

[API 23 screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgpiV.png)

In API 19 buttons cover the whole screen while API 23 doesn't cover.How to make API 23 buttons cover whole screen while maintaining API 19 buttons covering whole screen

Comment: Both images are the same. Perhaps you uploaded one of the files wrong?

Comment: Show xml file..

Comment: http://codepaste.net/jctb6b

Comment: Remove this _android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"_

Comment: You want to increase the size of button in API 23 correct?

Comment: @Piyush where it is present in the code?

Comment: Yes Multidots Solutions

Comment: @Navyasri In xml file for your parent _RelativeLayout_

Comment: You will need to use dimens.xml to support multiple screen size

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code. As text, not images or links

Comment: @Navyasri Did u remove as i said?

Comment: @Piyush i have removed still no change

Comment: @Multidots Solutions can u help me with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `dimens` file for supporting multiple screens. You can view official documentation for supporting multiple dimens here https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Edit :

Create new values folder with name as values-hdpi, values-xhdpi, values-xxhdpi, values-xxxhdpi.

Then add the button size in dimens file as below

values-hdpi

```
<dimen name="btn_click_me_width">18dp</dimen>
<dimen name="btn_click_me_height">18dp</dimen>
```

values-xhdpi

```
<dimen name="btn_click_me_width">24dp</dimen>
<dimen name="btn_click_me_height">24dp</dimen>
```

and similarly for other folders

You can calculate the size for different version here http://jennift.com/dpical.html

and in your layout file change button width as below

```
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_click_me_width"
```

[image: Dimens files]

Comment: sorry i didn't have internet connection these 2 days

Comment: @Multidotsolutions.Thanks for the help

Comment: both for lollipop and marshmallow is taking xhdpi dimensions.so when i see it in lollipop phone some part of the game is not seen.please help me multidot solutions